# Change R Leaftlet heatmap color to red

Tags: r, leaflet

Please, I will like to change Leaftlet KML heatmap color gradient to red in R

```
library(leaflet.extras)

kml <- readr::read_file(
  system.file("examples/data/kml/crimes.kml.zip", package = "leaflet.extras")
)

leaflet() %>%
  setView(-77.0369, 38.9072, 12) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addKMLHeatmap(kml, radius = 7) %>%
  addKML(
    kml,
    markerType = "circleMarker",
    stroke = FALSE, fillColor = "black", fillOpacity = 1,
    markerOptions = markerOptions(radius = 1))
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're after, but when dealing with heatmaps, it can sometimes help to adjust the `radius` value. For example, if you change that from 7 to 10, you get more intense colors and values. Try running this and see if it's what you're after. (I also changed the `fillOpacity` on the markers to .5 to show the heatmap a little more clearly)

```
library('leaflet.extras')

kml <- readr::read_file(
  system.file("examples/data/kml/crimes.kml.zip", package = "leaflet.extras")
)

leaflet() %>%
  setView(-77.0369, 38.9072, 12) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addKMLHeatmap(kml, radius = 10) %>%
  addKML(
    kml,
    markerType = "circleMarker",
    stroke = FALSE, fillColor = "black", fillOpacity = .5,
    markerOptions = markerOptions(radius = 1))
```

Comment: Thanks lot Sam, this is exactly what I want to achieve with the heatmap